# Difficulty with loop and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I'm trying to do a check via ajax various elements of an array. However, I am unable to run the loop correctly. can you help me?

https://jsfiddle.net/mzpsLvo6/

```
var codReferencia = ['1111','2222','3333','4444'];

$.each(codReferencia, function(index, val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://webapi.toqueacampainha.com.br/api/estoque/produtoprontaentrega?refid=" + codReferencia,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if ( data >= '1' ) {
            console.log('do anything');
        } else {
            console.log('do not do anything');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Now the problem is this , when I try to do a scan and image insertion for each item response '>= 1' I would like to display the image only for the item in that condition. Where am I going wrong in this stream? https://jsfiddle.net/uou5kfrx/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the entire array each time. You need to use your index argument and only pass the current element you are looping over.

```
var codReferencia = ['1111','2222','3333','4444'];

$.each(codReferencia, function(index, val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://webapi.toqueacampainha.com.br/api/estoque/produtoprontaentrega?refid=" + codReferencia[index],
        codeReference: codReferencia[index],
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if ( response >= '1' ) {
            console.log('do anything: ' + this.codeReference);
        } else {
            console.log('do not do anything');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I would like to display on the console a message for each item in the array... like this: console.log('do anything' + codReferencia[i]);

Comment: I added this.codeReference above to show you how to access data in the done handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had not realized :)

Comment: The `val` parameter already contains the value. There's no need to access the original array by index. You can also use it instead of `this.codeReference`.

Comment: Good call, Juhana. Forgot that was there. Not how I would've done this, just fixing the original code. I prefer lodash or underscore when looping over data.

Comment: Really! Both solutions are great. Thanks my friends.

Comment: @Juhana Now the problem is this , when I try to do a scan and image insertion for each item response '>= 1' I would like to display the image only for the item in that condition. Where am I going wrong in this stream? jsfiddle.net/uou5kfrx/2

Comment: @ScottMorgan ... Now the problem is this , when I try to do a scan and image insertion for each item response '>= 1' I would like to display the image only for the item in that condition. Where am I going wrong in this stream? jsfiddle.net/uou5kfrx/2

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uou5kfrx/3/ I added a data-id with the id that you are attempting to match, and if that exists in the jquery selector the image replaces the content of that element. For whatever reason I started getting cross-domain errors and 404 errors half way through development, not sure if you changed something on the webapi.toqueacampainha.com.br domain but it was working until those started up.

Comment: @ScottMorgan exactly :)! But... if I wanted to add this 'data-id' dynamically in the <p> element, as he would enter the flow?